# Is it always true that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) $?

Tags: probability

I saw this equation in a solution to a question, but maybe it's taken out of context. I didn't see this equation mentioned in the textbook.
So is the above equation always true?

Comment: This is true everywhere - drawing a Venn Diagram should help intuition. Notationally, $| A \cap B |$ is the what I've seen for the cardinality of a set - $P(A)$, as far as I can remember, is typically reserved for the power set of another set.

Comment: My first post here. downvoted. not sure why. People don't like easy questions?

Comment: I'm not sure why it got downvoted either.

Comment: People like questions with a lot of text on this site. As for the question: yes, it is always true and can in fact be derived from basic axioms of probability theory.

Comment: You have probably seen the equivalent $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{You must be very familiar with the equation}\;\;P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)\;\;\text{is just the same equation rearranged}$$